# Javascript XLS parsing function skips empty cells

Tags: javascript, excel, xls

On a web page, I need to load XLS Excel files and display the data into an HTML table.

I can't use XLSX files, only XLS ones.

To parse the file, I use `XLS.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array` function but it skips empty cells so the data is displayed in wrong columns. And I absolutely need to take empty cells into consideration.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which version you are using, but `js-xls` was merged into `js-xlsx` just FYI. If you update you should use `sheet_to_json` instead of `sheet_to_row_object_array`

And the solution is you just need to specify the default value.

```
XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(wb.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]], {defval: ""})
```

Comment: What library do I need to import ? Currently I use xlsx.core.min.js and xls.core.min.js

Comment: okay, then it is fine, you already use up-to-date version. Just add `{defval: ""}` and it should work